# Calling $(document).ready(function() {...}); from another file

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing

As the title suggested, I'm trying to call the $(document).ready(function() {...}); from another file.  The code snippet is as below:

Source file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert('document.ready function called!');
    // a lot of code
}
```

And in the test file:

```
TestFile.prototype.testDocumentReadyContents = function () {
    // test code here trying to call the document.ready function
}
```

I haven't had any success on it yet.  I have tried document.ready.apply(), trigger('ready'), overriding the document.ready function... but just couldn't call it.  FYI I'm invoking it as part of my unit test.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "another file"? Another JS file? An IFrame? An Ajax Request?

Comment: @ Pekka: source file is a .js file. test file is also another .js file. Their includes are in a configuration file which works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### GOOD WAY

```
$(document).ready(documentReady);

function documentReady() {
    alert('document.ready function called!');
    // a lot of code
}

TestFile.prototype.testDocumentReadyContents = function () {
    documentReady();
}
```

### Hackish Way

```
TestFile.prototype.testDocumentReadyContents = function () {
    $.readyList[0]();
}
```

Comment: @ ChaosPandion: I've been told that having the syntax $(document).ready(function() {...}); is a pretty standard jQuery thing. Therefore unless there is a serious violation of standards, or there is absolutely no other way to do it, I would prefer not to change the source code. Thanks.

Comment: There you go. I can't believe I took the time to figure this out. :)

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for... the "hackish Way"! Thankyou so much!  :D

Comment: What about if you're including several js files to your html, every one of them containing $(document).ready? The last one will override the previous documentReady functions.

Comment: @ChaosPandion I know is a very old answer but I have a similar question and maybe you can give me a solution https://stackoverflow.com/q/51947392/7882685

Comment: @BeraCim I know is old but have the same issue and cannot resolve it. If you are still here could you please check my question is a similar issue  stackoverflow.com/q/51947392/7882685