# How to call $(document).ready(function() {…}); from another file JS

Tags: javascript, sinon, teaspoon

I would like to know how to call the function below without refactoring from another js file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  check();

  function check () {
    setTimeout(function(){
      location.reload(true);
    }, 10000);
  }

});
```

I saw a question exist for this issue very old one but I cannot understand how to use the answer for my function.
[StackOverflow answer from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1870926/7882685)

I would like to see an example with my function and the proposed solution from the link.

My example which does not work correctly:

```
//= require rspec_helper
//= require background_index
//= require sinon



describe("Background Index, timeout after 10s", function() {
  // Tweak for testing
  var doc_ready = $.readyList[0]();

  it ("Reload the location", function(){
    clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();

    var check = doc_ready.check();
    var set_timeout = doc_ready.setTimeout();
    /*var stub_check = sinon.stub(check, "check");
    var stub_timeout = sinon.stub(timeout, "setTimeout");*/


    timedOut = false;



    setTimeout(function () {
      timedOut = true;
    }, 1000);


    timedOut.should.be.false;
    clock.tick(10010);
    timedOut.should.be.true;

    clock.restore();
  });

});
```

Comment: This works just fine, you just have to make sure that you load in jQuery before the other JS file.

Comment: You can't call that, it isn't a function. `$(document).ready(...)` is a function **call**.

Comment: So I need to refactor? But the answer I post is saying is possible. Can you please explain to me to understand.

Comment: @Jakub — I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Quentin what I need is to access this function for test it without refactoring as my CTO forbidden me any change in source code also after I told him that in this way is not testable and he 40yrs more experience of me so I have this situation

Comment: Then the question you probably should be asking is "How do I mock the things I need to mock in order to prove some specific thing?"

Comment: Maybe but still need to access it for be able to mock

Comment: @Jakub - This might be an opportunity to show initiative by giving your CTO a working refactoring for approval. It seems to me that such a refactoring would be minor.

Comment: @Jakub - How many calls to document.ready do you think exist in your application because the order will matter.

Answer (score 0):

This is re-written from the answer you pasted.

```
$(document).ready(check);

  function check () {
    setTimeout(function(){
      location.reload(true);
    }, 10000);
  }   

// In the test file
TestFile.prototype.testDocumentReadyContents = function () {
  check();
}
```

A better way would be to include all the JS-files in your HTML with `<script src="./path-to-file">` and then just call the functions in the order you want them to be called.

Comment: Ok and in the other answer is saying the Hack part to use only `TestFile.prototype.testDocumentReadyContents = function () {
    $.readyList[0]();
}` If you checked is separate from the other part is that what I do not understand.

Comment: What I understood from other answer to use `$.readyList[0]();` to access it from my JS file where I'm testing

Comment: @ChaosPandion: can you take a look

Comment: @Jakub He posts 2 different ways where the one I copied is "the good way". I think you should go for that one. Otherwise just copy the "hacky" part and use it instead of the last 3 lines in my answer.

Comment: I cannot refactor the code as I'm forbidden to do so. I cannot understand how with that $.readyList[0]() I could test that JS. I'm missing that part at all.

Comment: What is your code supposed to do? It looks like it should refresh the page after 10 secs once the document had loaded? What's the point in that?

Comment: The point is that I have a page in my RoR application which shows Background jobs and the reload happening to refresh and show the added new background jobs so that the point of it

Comment: Aren't you able to add the scripts with "require" in the manifest? What you're asking is a very uncommon practice and with good reason.

Comment: I added an example of what I'm trying to do