# Jest how to test function is called from $( document ).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, jestjs

Function which is called from $.ready is reported as not tested in code coverage .I need to write test case to cover function is getting called when document is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    fetchUser() // this line is reported as not tested in code coverage
});
```

Basically I need to mock function and I need to assert mock function is invoked when document is ready

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837382/how-to-invoke-document-readyfunction-in-unit-testing

Comment: I wouldn't unit test that, you're going to find out pretty quickly at the E2E level if your app isn't getting the data it needs to run.